# -vm arguments does not working on eclipse mars

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I have a problem using JBoss Tools in Eclipse Mars.

My native JDK in Ubuntu is 1.7, but for the Eclipse Mars, you must use the JDK 1.8 to load the JBoss Tools.

Then I changed this setting in my *eclipse.ini*, but still fails to load modules JBoss Tools:

**Eclipse error:**

[image: eclipse error]

**Config:**

[image: config]

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse.ini, remove the /java from the -vm path so it just ends in /bin